# HDFS on docker containers - is it possible?

Tags: docker, hadoop, hdfs, docker-swarm, hdp

we are using Hadoop cluster based on HDP version - `2.6.5` with ambari platform

we want to know if we can use the following HDFS components on docker containers as:

```
1. journal nodes 
2. ZK fail controller
3. NameNode ( HA with active namenode and standby namenode )
```

after some searching , we not found so much documentation about HDFS on  docker containers

so I am assume that `HDFS` on docker containers isnt good implementation

I will happy to get more ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera has no such documentation to my knowledge. They may be working on a future Kubernetes product offering, but that is just what I have heard.

Yes, it is possible to use Docker, but it would not be supported by any major Hadoop vendor, and it would probably be very difficult to handle networking and storage requirements around that.

[MinIO would arguably be a better alternative than HDFS when using Docker](https://blog.min.io/hdfsbenchmark/)

Comment: thank you so much cricket ( +1 ) , so I assume in the industry world and for production cluster no one implemented hdfs on docker am I right ?

Comment: do you can share any documentation about not using hdfs on containers on production systems?

Comment: As I said, Minio or Ceph or GlusterFS are more used in those such environments. Of course I have no documentation. You just need to go to any company running HDFS at reasonable scale

Comment: Or switch your whole environment completely away from HDP https://www.datanami.com/2018/11/20/inside-pachyderm-a-containerized-alternative-to-hadoop/

Comment: for now its not realistic , we want to continue with hadoop , but some teams from our company want to do it on docers ( i mean hdfs on dockers ) , from my point this is mistake because I not see one company that  use production HDFS on docker containers

Comment: the second point is about - how docker containers with HDFS will works under production env , with very fast read/write to disks and when disks on each node are huge with more then 30T

Comment: Speed and size doesn't matter. You'd just use Docker `volumes`. Anything can be containerized. But there's plenty of documented drawbacks putting a JVM container inside a Docker container. (do your own research)

Comment: Regarding networking, the namenode and datanodes all exist in the Docker Bridge / Overlay network. Clients would have to run in the same network space to use Hadoop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207766/discussion-between-jessica-and-cricket-007).